# How to transfer variable values from one Ink story to another Ink story? (in Unity C#)

Tags: unity-game-engine, inkle-ink

I have the following variable at globals.ink:

```
VAR affinity = ""
```

And the following in Scene1.ink:

```
~ affinity = "Shenzhen"
```

I want to pass affinity to Scene2.ink but I only get the variable value from globals.ink. I have tried to set value and get value through External functions, and tried to play with ObserveVariable. Nothing seems to work. And I cannot find any documentation on how to pass variable values to a different Ink story. I would appreciate any help.

I want the `affinity` variable to pass from Scene1.ink to Scene2.ink but I cannot manage to make it happen.